# How do you use Git with multiple users on same machine?

Tags: git

We all know you can set Git email and username in `git.config`.

What's the best approach when two users use the same machine?

Comment: They should have different user accounts on the machine, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of actions:

1. Create a dedicated group for these two users, and include them into the group. Re-login to apply the changes, if necessary.
2. Create a shared repo in a location accessible by the users. with `git init --shared`
3. Run `chown -R :<the_group> .` inside the repo.
4. Now your users may clone the repo (`git clone /path/to/the/repo` from within their home folders) and work each in their private repo clones with their own personal settings, including name and e-mail. They need to publish their work periodically with `git push`.

Answer (score 2):

If having separate user accounts was not an option, I'd write a small script to set these `GIT_AUTHOR_***` environment variables: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#Committing

Answer (score 1):

If you interested in adding user information on commits, you can set author on each commit.

```
git commit -m "some message" --author "user2@email.com"
```